# ImageView or ImageButton highlight?

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, highlight, android-imagebutton

How make pressed effect like on attached sreenshots??

[Normal state](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4S9ZMXYvi0TOGlvRG9BNnFZOHM/view?usp=docslist_api)

[Pressed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4S9ZMXYvi0TcGJtOU45TEE3RjA/view?usp=docslist_api)

Comment: make custom drawable. android:background="@drawable/like_button" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeactivepressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitialpressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeon"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitial"/>
</selector>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a selector for drawable. A selector defines a set of multiple images for different states of a view.
Create an xml with following contents in your drawable folder and set it as the background or src of your view(Button/ImageButton).

eg:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
> <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
> <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_default"/>
>
> </selector>
> ```

Use two different images for your pressed and normal states.